# Mudar várias palavras iguais na consulta do Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou tendo que lidar com uma quantidade muito grande de palavras iguais na minha consulta no Oracle e ter que mudar uma por uma cada uma delas cada vez que tenho que testar a consulta com um campo diferente está sendo cansativo. Alguém sabe se o Oracle disponibiliza mudar as palavras iguais todas de uma vez por outra? Similar ao que o sublime faz com o Ctrl + H.

Comment: Pode ser mais especifico? Eu acho que você esta falando do REPLACE, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Não kkkk perdão, vou editar a pergunta. Mas basicamente eu tenho que testar a mesma consulta com vários campos diferentes, ou seja eu quero substituir os nomes na consulta mesmo e não na tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que você quis dizer,No SQL Developer é o `crtl+f` ai você clica no 'Substituir'